# Can I create a vscode extension that is able to display variable names in a translated way without modifying the original souce code file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

is it possible to create a visual studio code extension that is able to display variables in a different way than stored in the original source code file. The idea is to translate the variables on programmer's side but obviously without changing the original source code file. By using the extension, the programmer should be able to see the variables in his preferred language (obviously the translation part gets done by an auxiliary algorithm/tool) and for example when hovering the "translated" source code line, the original code line gets displayed. In this way, the readability of source code could be improved, but source code files remain untouched.

**Example:**

A spanish-speaking programmer wrote the following code line:

`const número_de_personas: number = 10;`

For an english-speaking programmer it would be nice to see the previous code line as following:

`const number_of_persons: number = 10;`

This visual modification however should only take place locally on the english-speaking programmer side, without changing/translating the original source code file.

Is something like that possible to create as a vscode extension and how?

Comment: convince the Spanish programmer to use English variable names, the rest of the programming language is in English and can't be changed, are you also implementing all the language servers for all the supported languages

Comment: 1. I think such a thing should technically be possible, but don't know if it exists. 2. I think that's a really bad idea and a sure-fire way to get some broken communication/assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. It‘s completely clear, that the spanish programmer could write in english, however, the provided example was just a simple use case scenario in order to explain my question a bit better and to give a simple example that explains the question in a clearer way. The question I would like to ask is still: Is it possible to visualize parts of a code line in a different way without actually modifying the original source code file?